# communication between plc and c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plc

I have a Fatek PLC and I need to use its data in my C++ program which is written in Visual Studio IDE. I want this communication to be double sided, i.e. I want to use C++ program outputs in Fatek PLC and vice versa. How can I make this communication?
I should note that I am using FaconServer between Fatek PLC and my C++ program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please review: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [this protocol](http://www.fatek.com/en/data%2Fftp%2FPLC%2FFBs_Manual%2FManual_2%2FAppendix1.pdf) in your C++ application